# DIY woodshop cabinets

Tags: cabinetry

Not sure how you want me to re-word my question. Based on the title of the forum I figured I could ask for direction for a newby to look for help getting started in woodworking. Maybe I picked the wrong site. Is this just a place to boast about what you built?

I'm new to cabinet making. I would like to build a cabinet in my workshop with drawers and doors with shelves inside. Where can I look to find plans for constructing a cabinet frame from scratch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for plans and external resources.

Comment: This would encourage link only answers that are not guaranteed long term to help others.

Comment: Sorry for your confusion.  With good reason, [none of the sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153220/220382) on the StackExchange network permit questions that merely ask for external resources (like woodworking plans).  See the link for details, but the main reason is we're trying to build an enduring resource and community. Links to external resources go stale and that makes questions that ask for them have a much more limited lifespan.  Also, people that ask others to do their research often don't make good contributions to the community (though I'm not accusing you of that!).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at a few youtube videos on sites like

Stumpynubs: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCstwpLSByklww1YojZN-KiQ

The Wood WHisperer: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKp44bWWZIiOPShPN_ytShw

Down to Earth Wood Works : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI5vz5Jl1tFCPkGyHMT1y9Q

Each will have similar projects and offer download plans.

If might also suggest that you take a crack at making your own plans.  IF you are not familiar with it check out 'Sketchup Make' (free version @ http://www.sketchup.com/products/sketchup-pro/new-in-2016?gclid=CjwKEAiAgKu2BRDu1OGw3-KXokwSJAB_Yy2QJzGC6_HNK0vKWoQd9FKB1V4jWc9Q2W6a0FLvmN-W4BoCajjw_wcB).  It is a three dimensional drawing program and you can make your own plan based upon the plans you get on these sites. They have an online library called the 3D warehouse which is accesible from within the program. Many users have uploaded their own models there. Drawing it up yourself or modifying these models will quickly help you work out and understand the details. Although it has a little learning curve to begin with, it will quickly become one of your best tools.

Comment: Thank you Ashlar. This is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't asking for someone to send me plans. Just point me in the right direction to look. You understood what I was asking and you helped a fellow in need.

Comment: Your welcome & Come again.  I would suggest you edit/change the question.  Providing links to specific plans is not part of our scope.  Such questions become a shortcut for people to skip their own research, so members are concerned about doing it. It is ok to ask for direction, but questions are always better received when askers are seriously trying to solve their own question.  Ask a question and tell us what you have done so far. Tell us what is confusing or problematic. And please participate, read the material and upvote good questions and answers.

Comment: I meant to edit the question title